# Prestashop 1.7 Hook admin product does not display

Tags: hook, prestashop-1.7

I have a module on Prestashop that works on versions 1.6 and 1.7.

In version 1.6, I managed to display an additional field on the product sheet in the bacok office. I wish to do the same for version 1.7, but without success for now ...

I try with the displayAdminProductsMainStepLeftColumnMiddle hook

my controller of the module:

```
public function displayAdminProductsMainStepLeftColumnMiddle($params) {
    $product = new Product($params['id_product']);

    $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
        'id_product_jshop' => $product->id_product_jshop
        )
    );

    return $this->display(__FILE__, '/views/templates/1.7/admin/jshop.tpl');
```

The recording of the hook

```
$this->registerHook('displayAdminProductsMainStepLeftColumnMiddle');
```

and my view:

```
<div class="m-b-1 m-t-1">
<h2>{l s='Custom Attribute from module' mod='jshopimport'}</h2>

<fieldset class="form-group">
<div class="col-lg-12 col-xl-4">

<label class="form-control-label">{l s='ID JSHOP' mod='jshopimport'}</label>
<input type="text" name="id_product_jshop" class="form-control" {if $id_product_jshop && $id_product_jshop != ''}value="{$id_product_jshop}"{/if}/>

</div>
</fieldset>

<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Have you an idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For information, I found my error.

Before I was done in my install function :

```
$this->registerHook('displayAdminProductsMainStepLeftColumnMiddle'));

return parent::install();
```

With this solution, the hook was nor registered !!

The goot practice is :

```
if (!parent::install()
        || !$this->registerHook('displayAdminProductsExtra')
        || !$this->registerHook('displayAdminProductsMainStepLeftColumnMiddle')) {
            return false;
    }
```

It is important to do first

```
parent::install()
```

Answer (score 1):

The function must to start with "hook" and

```
public function hookDisplayAdminProductsMainStepLeftColumnMiddle($params)
```

and then you registering without hook

```
$this->registerHook('displayAdminProductsMainStepLeftColumnMiddle');
```

Comment: after that, try to go in your module page and reset it